# how to pick a percentage of data matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset, percentage

Hi I have a data set lets call it `dataset A` and this dataset consists of 500x10 samples. I have another `dataset B` which is the class labels for each of those rows.

```
Dataset A   | Dataset B 
1 0.2 | 0.3 = Green 
2 0.1 | 0.1 = Red 
3 0.2 | 0.4 = Blue
```

and so on...

I want to choose a percentage of blue and red from dataset A lets call it percentOfA and have another dataset which corresponds to that from dataset B, lets call it `ResultOfA` which is just matching colours to the percent of colours choosen from A.

So the new dataset `percentOfA` would look like:

```
1 0.2 | 0.4 
2 0.2 | 0.4 
3 0.2 | 0.4 
4 0.1 | 0.1
```

75% blue and 25% red, then the new `resultOfA` would look like this:

```
1 Blue.
2 Blue.
3 Blue.
4 Red.
```

How is this achieved in matlab?

Sorry I would try show code but I cant find anything for this in the documentation.

**NEW EDIT:**

So I am a tad lost on how to explain this better. Dataset B contains 500x1 of colours, Blue, Green, Red etc

This dataset B matches dataset A but dataset A contains numerical values of what constitutes those colours.

All I want to do is use dataset B to pick 75% of the blue colour and the ones it picked it keeps track of the row number and then uses those row numbers to take the data out of dataset A and put it into a new dataset.

So that way my "newdataset" will just be 75% of the blue colour and or also 25% red from dataset A (the numerical values).

Comment: How to pick?randomly?Also, 75% of all blue labels or just 75% of the rows you want to pick? And how many rows you want to pick?

Comment: @chaohuang  yes randomly pick 75% of just the blue label and corresponding rows in dataset A and randomly pick 25% of just the red etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [`crossvalind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) function in the Bioinformatics toolbox, specifically with the `Group` parameter. It will make your life a lot easier by not needing to code this functionality on your own.

In your case, you would simply do something like:

```
percentage = 75;
[train, test] = crossvalind('HoldOut', B, size(A, 1), percentage/100);
percentOfA = A(train, :);
resultOfA = B(train, :);
```

Comment: In this example how does it know what the 25% and 75% are?

Comment: If you already know what they are, then you don't need all this. You can simply make a vector with the indices, and then choose a subset of the `A` and `B` matrices.

Comment: Yes dataset B is the index to dataset A but I want to create a new dataset which has a certain percentage of what ever I want to choose.

Comment: I thought B had the labels? The code above will let you define a percentage and then randomly choose that much from A

Comment: Sorry yes dataset B has the labels ignore what I said. Im kind of looking for a word match here, for instance: Choose 75% of rows which contain Blue from dataset B get the index pretaining to dataset A of those rows and output the actual values from dataset A that are blue to a new dataset. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

First use `find` to determine the `blue` rows: `idx=find(B==0.4);`

Then randomly choose 75% of those `blue` rows:

```
n = numel(idx);
n75 = round(n*0.75);
r = randperm(n);
idx_blue = idx(r(1:n75));
```

The corresponding `blue` rows of `A` is: `A_blue = A(idx_blue);`

Repeat the steps to choose `red` rows.

HTH.

Comment: No this isnt what im looking for B==0.4, blue could be variable I justed used 0.4 as an example. Dataset B is in the same order as Dataset A i need another method.

Comment: @KirstyWhite if blue is a variable, then how you determine which rows are blue.

Comment: by its indx. When I create the sample from another dataset i create an indx of the labels to numeric dataset you can do the same here.

Comment: @KirstyWhite you don't need to use the `find` function to determine the 'blue' rows, just use the indx you created to find them, then the remain steps are the same.